# SCP stuck on file copying

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I have a test file with a simple text inside. 
If filesize more then 750 bytes I can not transfer it via SCP or rsync.

Internet works fine on the host and has Download: 16.53 Mbit/s Upload: 2.83 Mbit/s

```
-rw-rw-r--  1  4395 Nov  4 18:34 test

 scp -v  ./test  deployer@vpn-test_host:/home/deployer

debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/deployer
Sending file modes: C0664 4395 test
Sink: C0664 4395 test
test                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
```

I tried fetching from the other machine and it works. 
But doesn't work for sending it.

Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on both sides. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you SSH to the remote host?

Comment: are you transmitting through a VPN ? thinking about a [PMTUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) issue.

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to the host, I tried fetching from the other machine and it works. But doesn't work for sending a file. Yeah, I am transmitting through an OpenVPN and I  decreased the MTU to 1460

Comment: Have you got write permissions on [target directory in] the remote computer? Is the ISP preventing uploading?

Comment: Yeah, I have write permissions on the remote host and can transfer small files like a 1-byte text file with 5 lines inside but if I add 20 lines of text inside the file. I can not transfer and it stuck.